# PHP redirect without change current url?

Tags: php, flash, .htaccess, redirect, mp3

We have some mp3 file collection and flash player used this mp3 file, to track mp3 file listing we render mp3 file using php file below is code

http://www/example.com/getFile.php?fileid=12

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['fileid'];

// Some code to store download traking and get filename for this id in $filename var.
$filename = getFileName($id);

header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: filename=' . $id . '.mp3');
readfile($filename);

?>
```

But mp3 file size in very big and player get break in IE, for that we also use below code

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['fileid'];

// Some code to store download traking and get filename for this id in $filename var.
$filename = getFileName($id);

header('Location: '. $filename);
?>
```

this code working fine but its also chnages current URL
i.e http://www/example.com/getFile.php?fileid=12  to  http://www/example.com/files/xyz.mp3

so user can easily download mp3 file direct how i prevent this? using php or other way ?

Comment: Even with your first solution, the user can easily download the file. **A request to a URL returns data, either way you slice it.** This data can be saved. How this data is output exactly serverside is irrelevant.

Comment: And no, you can't redirect without changing the URL. That's the definition of a redirect: to change the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Sorry, didn't read the question properly when I originally posted - I see now that the problem is with IE and large file size)

You could try telling IE the length, and flushing the buffers:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

Let Flash fetch the file. Return just the URL to Flash through the PHP.